# Calling a function using "this"

Tags: jquery, html, forms

My HTML is :

```
<table class="tableData" id="addUserTable" >
    <tr>
        <th class = "" name="errorMsgUser" id="errorMsg" value="" colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class= "" > Desired Username </th>
        <td><input name="desUname" type="text" id="desUname" size="30" value=""  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class= "" > Password </th>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>               
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td>
            <input name="submitAddUser" type="submit" id="submitAddUser" value="Add User" />
            <input type="button" value="Clear All" id="clearUpdateForm"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've made a generic function which clears a form and focuses the first input box

```
$.clearForm = function() {
    var parentEle = $(this).closest('form');
    parentEle.find(':input').each(function() {
        switch(this.type) {
            case 'password':
            case 'select-multiple':
            case 'select-one':
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                $(this).val('');
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                this.checked = false;
        }});
    parentEle.find('input[type=text]:first').focus();
};
```

how do i now call this function on a form ? For eg, given given the markup as above, can I bind the function as such :

```
$(function(){$("#clearUpdateForm").click(function(){
    $.clearForm (this);
});});
```

Comment: 'the minus sign' ... I really don't understand your Q.

Comment: Your function is named clearForm, but you are calling resetForm.  Typo?

Comment: The title still makes no sense at all please change it to reflect your actual question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're going to have to make a decision. Either you are passing "this" as a parameter to the function, or your function is acting on the context of "this".

**1) pass an element as a parameter:** Here you are using "this" as a pointer to an element on which you would like your function to act. Your function must always be told explicitly on what to do its business.

```
$.clearForm = function(target) {
    var parentEle = $(target).closest('form');
    ...
};
$("#clearUpdateForm").click(function(){
    $.clearForm(this);
});
```

**2) set the context of your function:** Here your function acts on the object in who's context it is. We can use .call or .apply to set the context manually.

```
$.clearForm = function() {
    var parentEle = $(this).closest('form');
    ...
};
$("#clearUpdateForm").click(function(){
    $.clearForm.call(this);
});
```

Stick with the first technique. The second is useful for making a chainable jquery method but not what you want to do here.

There are many resources for reading about function [parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)/[scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)/[ways-to-call-a-function](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the `jQuery.fn` object like this:

```
jQuery.fn.clearForm = function() {
  // `this` is a DOM element now.
  var parentEle = $(this).closest('form');
  doOtherStuff();
};
```

Then you can easily invoke it on a jQuery object that is your form like this:

```
$('#clearUpdateForm').clearForm();
```

---

The `jQuery.fn` object defines methods available on jQuery wrapped objects.  Any extensions you make to it are made available to all jQuery wrapped objects.